# Excerpt's length

Tags: wordcount, synopsis, excerpt

How long, or how short, should and excerpt be?

In entering mine for NaNoWriMo I noticed it was over 500 words long. Generally speaking, how long should a good excerpt be?

Should I treat it as I would the synopsis? In length I mean.

Comment: hmmm the excerpt i am doing is about 700 words long. When I think of an excerpt, I think of what will draw the reader to want to read more. It's your one chance to give them a sample of your writing to see if it interests them or not. When I think about books when they give you a preview, usually it's a couple pages worth so length may not be an issue.

Comment: Good point. So, maybe mine is too short lol.

Comment: Are you asking about the rules of NANOWRIMO particularly? If so, please clarify. If you are talking about excerpts in general, please clarify the purpose of a except for your use case, since there is no inherent length requirement for a except generally.

Comment: @MarkBaker no, I mean in general. I don't intend to stop with NaNoWriMo ;) I envision this to be like "target practice", but I am curious to find out just how long is a good excerpt supposed to be.

Comment: Well, an excerpt can be any length. It depends entirely on the length of the work and the purpose of the excerpt. Unless you can narrow down the use case, I don't think this question is answerable.

Comment: @MarkBaker I think you and ggiaquin already replied. Thank you. I'll rework my excerpt and probably it'll be even longer.